# How do I resolve this PHP Fatal Error in Akeneo 3.0.15?

Tags: php, symfony, akeneo

I'm trying to install the Woocommerce Bundle for Akeneo 3.0.15 and I'm receiving the following error:

`Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Webkul\\WooCommerceBundle\\WooCommerceBundle' not found in /var/www/akeneo/pim-community-standard/app/AppKernel.php:24\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/akeneo/pim-community-standard/app/AppKernel.php(34): AppKernel->registerProjectBundles()\n#1 /var/www/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(488): AppKernel->registerBundles()\n#2 /var/www/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(132): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->initializeBundles()\n#3 /var/www/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(195): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->boot()\n#4 /var/www/akeneo/pim-community-standard/web/app.php(30): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request))\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/akeneo/pim-community-standard/app/AppKernel.php on line 24\n'`

My AppKernel.php file has the following function and the call for the Woocommerce Bundle on line 24:

```
    {
        return [
            // your app bundles should be registered here
            new Webkul\WooCommerceBundle\WooCommerceBundle(),
            new Visionit\EnhancedImportBundle\VisionitEnhancedImportBundle()
        ];
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't want to be rude but `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Webkul\\WooCommerceBundle\\WooCommerceBundle' not found` seem to be a pretty explicit error... Did you import the class in your use statment ?

Comment: Hi @Pierre. Yes, I have. There was an issue with the file, which the developer took care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer addressed issues with the provided files.